# Routes Permission in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

Hello I am putting security in my app angular, is that the user is not logged can not access any route of the administration, in this case I have this code:

```
app.run(function($rootScope, $location, loginService){
    var routespermission=['/admin','/products','/products/','/products/:id/edit','/productos/:id/delete'];  //route that require login
    $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeStart', function(){
        if( routespermission.indexOf($location.path()) !=-1)
        {
            var connected=loginService.islogged();
            connected.then(function(msg){
                if(!msg.data) $location.path('/login');
            });
        }
    });
});
```

The first routes works fine but when using urls with format "products/1/edit" are shown to the user not logged, it seems that something is missing in this part so that the user can not edit and delete records

Comment: `$location.path` is going to return the *real* path (i.e. `/products/someuserid/edit`) which isn't going to be in your array.

Answer (score 1):

I'm no security expert but I do the following in my app. I assign a permission on the route itself and in the run I use a service that contains my current user's permissions and check if the user contains the required permission.

```
    $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeStart', function (event, next, current) {
        if (next.permission !== undefined && next.permission !== null) {
            if (!permissionStore.hasPermission(next.permission)) {
                $location.path('/');
            }
        }
    });
```

On the route itself:

```
    $routeProvider
        .when('/SomeRoute',
    {
        templateUrl: 'something.html',
        controller: 'SomeController',
        controllerAs: 'vm',
        permission: 'Some Permission'
    });
```

So if the user does not have 'Some Permission' it will redirect them. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something similar to this using ui-router. Below i have define states as example and function to block routes based on condition. I do the following in my app.

```
.state('products', {
                url: '/products',
                views: {
                    'pageContent@': {
                        templateUrl: 'app/views/products/product.html',
                        controller: 'productController',
                        controllerAs: 'vm'
                    }
                }
            })

    .state('products_os', {
                url: '/products',
                views: {
                    'pageContent@': {
                        templateUrl: 'app/views/products/product_os.html',
                        controller: 'productOsController',
                        controllerAs: 'vm'
                    }
                }
            })      

 $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) {

                    var restrictedRoute: ['admin', 'products','product_os'];

                    angular.forEach($http.pendingRequests, function(request) {
                        request.canceler.resolve();
                    });

                    if (toState.name === "login" && authenticationService.IsAuthenticated() === true) {
                         return $state.go('products');         
                    } else {
                         authenticationService.clearCredentials();
                         $state.go('login');
                    }

                    if ($.inArray(fromState.name, restrictedRoutes) === -1) return;
        });
```

Hope this helps you. Thanks